# SMBIOS 3 Get Structure table address and number of structures

Tags: c, kernel, hardware, osdev, bios

I'm coding an [standalone smbios library](https://github.com/TretornESP/smbios). Following the [standard 3.6.0 by DMTF](https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.6.0.pdf).

> See edit for a partial answer (Unsure if it is optimal)

It works just fine for SM tables (32 bits) but I can't seem to grasp how to start iterating the SM3 (64 bits) version.

The first problem I'm facing is stepping from the *entry point structure* to the structure tables themselves, as the *Structure Table Address* field `(Table 2, offset 0x10, page 27)` is not a valid physical address. Running QEMU it gives me the address: `0x3f9a90000000`

My structure definition is:

```
struct smbios3_entry_point {
    char entry_point_string[5];    //This is _SM3_
    uint8_t checksum;              //This value summed with all the values of the table, should be 0 (overflow)
    uint8_t length;                //Length of the Entry Point Table. Since version 2.1 of SMBIOS, this is 0x1F
    uint8_t major_version;          //Major Version of SMBIOS
    uint8_t minor_version;          //Minor Version of SMBIOS+
    uint8_t doc_rev;               //Document Revision
    uint8_t entry_point_revision;    //...
    uint8_t reserved;             //Checksum for values from EntryPointString2 to the end of table
    uint16_t max_structure_size;     //Maximum size of a SMBIOS Structure (we will se later)
    uint64_t table_address;         //Address of the Table
} __attribute__((packed));
```

And I'm checking the string against `_SM3_` and also checking the checksum.

```
(gdb) p/x entry
$3 = 0xffff80003f9aa000
(gdb) p/x *entry
$4 = {entry_point_string = {0x5f, 0x53, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x5f}, checksum = 0xfe, length = 0x18, major_version = 0x3,
  minor_version = 0x0, doc_rev = 0x0, entry_point_revision = 0x1, reserved = 0x0, max_structure_size = 0x1eb,
  table_address = 0x3f9a90000000}
```

All the fields but the last one seem to make sense.

So the questions here are pretty straightforward:

1. Does that address `0x3f9a90000000` make sense?
2. If so: ¿To which physical address should I map it?

A bonus question here: In the 64-bit entry structure there is no: "Number of structures field" like in smbios32. So ¿is it correct to parse the structures by just iterating the range

```
(address)->(address+max_size)

void init_smbios64(struct smbios3_entry_point * entry, struct smbios_data* data) {
    
    struct smbios_header* header = (struct smbios_header *)(uint64_t)entry->table_address;
    void * max_address = (void*)((uint64_t)header + entry->max_structure_size);

    while ((void*)header < max_address && header->handle != 0) {
        printf("Header: %p, Type: %d, Length: %d, Handler: %x\n", header, header->type, header->length, header->handle);
        process_smbios_table(entry->major_version, entry->minor_version, header, data);
        header = (struct smbios_header *)((uint64_t)header+header->length);
        header = (struct smbios_header *)((uint64_t)header+(uint64_t)get_smbios_string_length((void*)header));
    }
}
```

For clarification I'm writing a 64-bit kernel, using limine as bootloader (getting smbios's entry point from there) and I'm using QEMU as my vm platform (With custom smbios specs). This code is all running in long mode with paging enabled.

```
#-smbios type=0[,vendor=str][,version=str][,date=str][,release=%d.%d][,uefi=on|off]
QSMBIOS0_ENTRIES := type=0,vendor=bm_vendor,version=bm_version,date=bm_date,release=1.0,uefi=on
#-smbios type=1[,manufacturer=str][,product=str][,version=str][,serial=str][,uuid=uuid][,sku=str][,family=str]
QSMBIOS1_ENTRIES := type=1,manufacturer=bm_manufacturer,product=bm_product,version=bm_version,serial=bm_serial,uuid=00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF,sku=bm_sku,family=bm_family
#-smbios type=2[,manufacturer=str][,product=str][,version=str][,serial=str][,asset=str][,location=str]
QSMBIOS2_ENTRIES := type=2,manufacturer=bm_manufacturer,product=bm_product,version=bm_version,serial=bm_serial,asset=bm_asset,location=bm_location
#-smbios type=3[,manufacturer=str][,version=str][,serial=str][,asset=str][,sku=str]
QSMBIOS3_ENTRIES := type=3,manufacturer=bm_manufacturer,version=bm_version,serial=bm_serial,asset=bm_asset,sku=bm_sku
#-smbios type=4[,sock_pfx=str][,manufacturer=str][,version=str][,serial=str][,asset=str][,part=str][,processor-id=%d]
QSMBIOS4_ENTRIES := type=4,sock_pfx=bm_sock_pfx,manufacturer=bm_manufacturer,version=bm_version,serial=bm_serial,asset=bm_asset,part=bm_part,processor-id=1
#-smbios type=11[,value=str][,path=filename]
QSMBIOS11_ENTRIES := type=11,value=bm_value,path=./bm_oem
#-smbios type=17[,loc_pfx=str][,bank=str][,manufacturer=str][,serial=str][,asset=str][,part=str][,speed=%d]
QSMBIOS17_ENTRIES := type=17,loc_pfx=bm_loc_pfx,bank=bm_bank,manufacturer=bm_manufacturer,serial=bm_serial,asset=bm_asset,part=bm_part,speed=1333
#-smbios type=41[,designation=str][,kind=str][,instance=%d][,pcidev=str]
QSMBIOS41_ENTRIES := type=41,designation=bm_designation,kind=ethernet,instance=1,pcidev=bm_pcidev

QSMBIOS := -smbios $(QSMBIOS0_ENTRIES) -smbios $(QSMBIOS2_ENTRIES) -smbios $(QSMBIOS3_ENTRIES)
```

Thank you so much and have a great day!

**Edit 1:**

Perhaps I'm having a type conversion problem, as shifting 16 bits to the right gives me the correct address. My code now is:

```
void init_smbios64(struct smbios3_entry_point * entry, struct smbios_data* data) {
    uint8_t *table_ptr = (uint8_t *)((uintptr_t)entry->table_address >> 16);

    uint8_t *end_of_table = table_ptr + entry->length;
    
    while (table_ptr < end_of_table) {
        struct smbios_header *header = (struct smbios_header *)table_ptr;
        
        // Call the process_smbios_table function for each structure
        process_smbios_table(entry->major_version, entry->minor_version, header, data);
        
        // Move to the next structure
        table_ptr += header->length;
    }
}
```